# Stack and queue to print the power set of n elements

Tags: java, stack, queue

Given an n-length Set of elements, is it possible to create a (non-recursive) loop of some kind that will iterate over and print the power set of the Set, using only 1 stack and 1 queue?

I've been "hard-coding" the problem with `queue.enqueue()` and `stack.push()` and trying to printout the queue to 'capture' each unique set:

```
int[] set = {1,2,3};
for (int aSet : set) {
    stack.push(aSet);
}

queue.printQ(queue);    // empty

queue.enqueue(stack.pop());
queue.printQ(queue);    // '3'

queue.enqueue(stack.pop());
stack.push(queue.dequeue());
queue.printQ(queue);    // '2'
// etc...
```

And while I can do that, I haven't found any pattern from which to base a loop. I've tried binary patterns, and starting off with either stack or queue full or empty, but each time there are unique statements that throw off any pattern that I can see.

Comment: Side note: **every** algorithm may be written in non-recursive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework problem. So here is the solution to the puzzle in Python, using a deque. You may convert it to Java on your own:

```
from collections import deque

def power_set(s):
    q = deque()
    q.appendleft([])
    for elem in reversed(s):
        while True:
            subset = q.pop()
            q.appendleft([elem] + subset)
            q.appendleft(subset)
            if not subset: break
    return list(q)
```